# Stray end tag head - cannot recover when validating

Tags: html, validation

I've looked at many of the similar threads on here and tried out the suggestions, but I'm getting nowhere. I'm trying to validate my site, but it's coming up with 3 errors and then stopping processing -

url: http://www.dominosvouchers-uk.co.uk

Line 39, Column 7: Stray end tag head. `</head>`

Line 41, Column 122: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.
**… sidebar-b-right isblog " data-config='{"twitter":0,"plusone":0,"facebook":0}'>**

Line 41, Column 122: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
**… sidebar-b-right isblog " data-config='{"twitter":0,"plusone":0,"facebook":0}'>**

Can anyone help me work out why? Is it just because HTML is so full of holes? The site seems to work OK.. but a bit worrying that it 'cannot recover after last error' and stops.

Comment: What are you using to validate your page? Try the W3 validator.

Comment: The only errors you have in that page is width="203px" height="203px" which should be CSS or have the px removed http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dominosvouchers-uk.co.uk&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had used the rel=author tag incorrectly, and should have been

```
<a rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/108165491209678636768" />    (added self closing tag, and seems to have fixed it :))
```

Comment: Thanks for input guys, I think I fixed it as I posted the question :S

Incidentally, what is the best way to test a site / code on a domain that uses 'expires' headers, browser caching etc? It seems the w3c validator doesn't retest the sample code a fresh each time, but uses the same cached version, leading me to think I've not fixed the error, when in reality it is..

Comment: Add a random number to the end of the URL might work `http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dominosvouchers-uk.co.uk/?rnd=12345&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0`